# How to regain Login Portlet in liferay

Tags: authentication, liferay, portlet, invisible

I am new to liferay 5.1 technology.

I by mistake removed the login portlet and now I am not able to login into the application.

I mean login portlet is no more visible any help would be of great help.

Comment: Good question, did either of the answers help you? If so, maybe you might want to accept one of them, or comment on what else you might need.

Answer (score 11):

Can you please try hitting the following url?

> localhost:8080/c/portal/login

Replace host and port with your host and port number.

If it doesnt work out  try doing the following.(Make sure the package is correct as i am not aware of package path in 5.1)

http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/5005621

Answer (score 8):

Actually, with enough persistence, it would be also possible to lock yourself out of access to `/c/portal/login` (as of Liferay 6.0.6). This can be done by setting community home page to a hidden "redirect" page (as opposed to default "portlet" page), causing /c/portal/login to redirect wherever the home page redirects.

Liferay tries to prevent from doing so by issuing alerts whenever you try to make home page hidden. But you can make some page hidden and then drag&drop it to the first position in site map root level.

The reason behind doing so is to achieve a certain appearance of portal navigation (which would otherwise require some mangling in theme), i.e. make home page redirect to one of it's children.

Going back to the topic, when `/c/portal/login` fails, there is one another, more reliable (yet more ugly) method of getting to what one would call a login page - append this: `?p_p_id=58&p_p_state=maximized` to any non-redirecting Liferay page (and probably drop any other GET parameters if existent). This is also basically what `/c/portal/login` does - but it appends it to home page, so if home page is a redirect page it fails display login portlet in it's maximized state.