# Liferay Portal 6.0 Community Edition - StackOverflowError when modifying the template

Tags: jakarta-ee, liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme

I modified the default template -

- portal_normal.ftl
- portal_normal.vm

added a few tags -

```
...
            <h1 class="site-title">
                <a class="${logo_css_class}" href="${site_default_url}" title="<@liferay.language key="go-to" /> ${site_name}">
                    <img alt="${logo_description}" height="${site_logo_height}" src="${site_logo}" width="${site_logo_width}" />
                </a>

...my tags here..

                <#if show_site_name>
                    <span class="site-name" title="<@liferay.language key="go-to" /> ${site_name}">
                        ${site_name}
                    </span>
                </#if>
            </h1>
...
```

Now, when I try to log in, I see a blank screen and in the log states that -

**catalina.out**:

```
...
    INFO: Server startup in 164719 ms
    06:23:13,302 ERROR [http-bio-8082-exec-3][IncludeTag:253] Current URL /web/guest/main?p_p_id=58&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=maximized&p_p_mode=view&saveLastPath=0&_58_struts_action=%2Flogin%2Flogin generates exception: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    06:23:13,316 ERROR [http-bio-8082-exec-3][IncludeTag:154] java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.io.unsync.UnsyncPrintWriter.write(UnsyncPrintWriter.java:385)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.write(JspWriterImpl.java:325)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.io.unsync.UnsyncPrintWriter.write(UnsyncPrintWriter.java:385)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.write(JspWriterImpl.java:325)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.io.unsync.UnsyncPrintWriter.write(UnsyncPrintWriter.java:385)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.write(JspWriterImpl.java:325)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.io.unsync.UnsyncPrintWriter.write(UnsyncPrintWriter.java:385)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.write(JspWriterImpl.java:325)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.io.unsync.UnsyncPrintWriter.write(UnsyncPrintWriter.java:385)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.write(JspWriterImpl.java:325)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.io.unsync.UnsyncPrintWriter.write(UnsyncPrintWriter.java:385)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.write(JspWriterImpl.java:325)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.io.unsync.UnsyncPrintWriter.write(UnsyncPrintWriter.java:385)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.write(JspWriterImpl.java:325)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.io.unsync.UnsyncPrintWriter.write(UnsyncPrintWriter.java:385)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.write(JspWriterImpl.java:325)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.io.unsync.UnsyncPrintWriter.write(UnsyncPrintWriter.java:385)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.write(JspWriterImpl.java:325)
        at com.liferay.portal.kernel.io.unsync.UnsyncPrintWriter.write(UnsyncPrintWriter.java:385)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspWriterImpl.write(JspWriterImpl.java:325)
...
```

What is this exception and how to log in now?

I guess that is not the point.
I returned everything as it was, but the log in is not possible - a blank screen.

Trying to restore the login portlet by typing `http://localhost: 8082/c/portal/login` in url.

When I look at the firebug, I see that the status of the login request:

`http://localhost:8082/c/portal/login?p_l_id=10691` is **302 Moved Temporarily**

What could this mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. Need to add the following in the properties of portal-ext.properties:

> auto.login.hooks=com.liferay.portal.security.auth.CASAutoLogin,com.liferay.portal.security.auth.NtlmAutoLogin,com.liferay.portal.security.auth.OpenIdAutoLogin,com.liferay.portal.security.auth.OpenSSOAutoLogin,com.liferay.portal.security.auth.RememberMeAutoLogin,com.liferay.portal.security.auth.SiteMinderAutoLogin,com.liferay.portal.security.auth.ParameterAutoLogin

Next, need to make the following request:

```
http://localhost:8082/web/guest?parameterAutoLoginLogin=some_email&parameterAutoLoginPassword=some_password
```

Now everything is Ok.

More information can be found here:

- [ParameterAutoLogin example](http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/5005621)
- [How to regain Login Portlet in liferay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10597031/how-to-regain-login-portlet-in-liferay)